# Background should take the entire space and

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

This is what I'm trying to achieve, the current issues are:

- the background is currently affecting only the container, I want it to take the entire place
- there has to be space in between the cards and padding inside the cards

[image]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Card, Paper } from '@mui/material';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import { amber, orange } from '@mui/material/colors';

import FormOne from './../src/FormOne';

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
  { field: 'title', headerName: 'Title', width: 300 },
  { field: 'body', headerName: 'Body', width: 600 },
];

const LoadingSkeleton = () => (
  <Box
    sx={{
      height: 'max-content',
    }}
  >
    {[...Array(10)].map((_) => (
      <Skeleton variant="rectangular" sx={{ my: 4, mx: 1 }} />
    ))}
  </Box>
);

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // fetch data from fake API
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(
      () =>
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setPosts(data);
            setLoading(false);
          }),
      3000
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container
      maxWidth="lg"
      sx={{
        background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${amber[300]}, ${orange[500]})`,
      }}
    >
      <Card>
        <FormOne />
      </Card>

      <Card>
        <Paper sx={{ height: '300px', width: '100%' }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={posts}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={10}
            // autoHeight
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            disableColumnMenu
            disableColumnSelector
            components={{
              LoadingOverlay: LoadingSkeleton,
            }}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </Paper>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you will need to add remove margin and apply 100% of height to `body` and `#root` element. I have added this so `style.css` imported inside `index.tsx`

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Next step would be to set `maxWidth` props to `false`, so it will be fulwidth.

I have added of course more stylings to your example to achieve the needed result(I hope i did it the way you imagined).

You can preview codesandbox [here](https://ccb1tr.csb.app/) and edit the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-feather-ccb1tr?file=/src/App.tsx:1269-1277)

p.s. I didnt have your `FormOne` component so I replaced it for now with simple input

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to put the cards a bit more to the middle, like margin-left: 25% margin-right: 25%, not what's right with mui. Just like it is on the drawing. It probably means that the cards should be in a box with margins left and right.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have edited the code, so you see the preview. Sorry that mockup got me confused hehe. If this answer please mark as an answer

Comment: There is a bug tho. When I put back `autoHeight` to `DataGrid` and remove `Paper`'s `height: 500px`, the gradient is left behind https://i.imgur.com/fbC9TyE.png. In order to reproduce it, `<Paper sx={{ padding: 10 }}>` and uncomment `autoHeight` from DataGrid.

Comment: You need to add overflow: auto to Container, i've edited the sandbox